# Jenkins 2, we are not able to save the system config

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

Since we upgraded to Jenkins 2, we are not able to save the system config.

When we click on the Save (or Apply) button, we are getting this error:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.docker.proxy.BuildInfoProxyManager$1; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID
```

We are using the Artifactory plugin to push the Maven artefacts to our Artifactory instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this Jenkins issue:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40907

This is a bug with the Artifactory plugin.

Upgrading to the version 2.9 (or more) fixed our issue.